# Consume a source with two sinks and get the result of one sink

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'd like to consume a `Source` with two different sinks.

Simplified example:

```
val source = Source(1 to 20)

val addSink = Sink.fold[Int, Int](0)(_ + _)
val subtractSink = Sink.fold[Int, Int](0)(_ - _)

val graph = GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))

  source ~> bcast.in

  bcast.out(0) ~> addSink
  bcast.out(1) ~> subtrackSink

  ClosedShape
}

RunnableGraph.fromGraph(graph).run()

val result: Future[Int] = ???
```

I need to be able to retrieve the result of `addSink`. `RunnableGraph.fromGraph(graph).run()` gives me `NotUsed`,
but I'd like to get an `Int` (the result of the first fold `Sink`). Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass in both sinks to the graph builder's `create` method, which gives you access to their respective materialized values:

```
val graph = GraphDSL.create(addSink, subtractSink)((_, _)) { implicit builder =>
  (aSink, sSink) =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))

  source ~> bcast.in
  bcast.out(0) ~> aSink
  bcast.out(1) ~> sSink
  ClosedShape
}

val (addResult, subtractResult): (Future[Int], Future[Int]) =
  RunnableGraph.fromGraph(graph).run()
```

Alternatively, you can forgo the graph DSL and use [`alsoToMat`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/alsoTo.html#alsoto):

```
val result: Future[Int] =
  Source(1 to 20)
    .alsoToMat(addSink)(Keep.right)
    .toMat(subtractSink)(Keep.left)
    .run()
```

The above gives you the materialized value of `addSink`. If you want to get the materialized value of both `addSink` and `subtractSink`, use `Keep.both`:

```
val (addResult, subtractResult): (Future[Int], Future[Int]) =
  Source(1 to 20)
    .alsoToMat(addSink)(Keep.right)
    .toMat(subtractSink)(Keep.both) // <--
    .run()
```